# 2 routers, 2 networks, 2 network connections, 1 computer

Tags: networking

I live in a house with 2 dsl connections each with their own router, hence two networks. I would like to access the LAN on the second network using a wifi dongle and continue using the internet on my primary network.

I don't want to use the internet connection on the second network as I will cap it. Only LAN access.

Thanks =)

Comment: Make sure both have differing subnets (e.g. Primary 192.168.1.x + Secondary 192.168.2.x)(255.255.255.0 mask) and make sure your primary network (the Internet LAN) router is your default gateway (make sure the other network doesn't have a default gateway otherwise you'll get both interfaces fighting and it won't work... not tried it, sounds logical though...

Comment: Thanks so much @BigChris not putting a gateway and setting the IP manually sorted it out.. ^_^